# How to break apart a complex line segment into simple line segments between all points?

Tags: postgis, linestring, simplify

Take for instance a very complex line string.. which has WKT like this `LINESTRING(1 1,2 2,3 3,4 4,5 5 ...)`  I want to create two-point linestrings from many-point linestrings.

```
SELECT ST_MakeLine(ST_MakePoint(x,x)) AS l
FROM generate_series(1,10) AS x
```

To break down into simple linestrings between all points.

```
      linesegment      
-----------------------
 LINESTRING(1 1,2 2)
 LINESTRING(2 2,3 3)
 LINESTRING(3 3,4 4)
 LINESTRING(4 4,5 5)
 LINESTRING(5 5,6 6)
 ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here we use [`generate_series`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html) and [`ST_NPoints()`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_NPoints.html) to generate the index into the line. And, [`ST_PointN()`](http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_PointN.html) to get the specific points.

```
WITH t AS (
  SELECT ST_MakeLine(ST_MakePoint(x,x)) AS l
  FROM generate_series(1,10) AS x
)
SELECT ST_AsText(
  ST_MakeLine(ST_PointN(t.l,gs), ST_PointN(t.l,gs+1))
) AS linesegment
FROM t
CROSS JOIN LATERAL generate_series(1,ST_NPoints(t.l)-1)
  WITH ORDINALITY AS gs
ORDER BY ordinality;

      linesegment      
-----------------------
 LINESTRING(1 1,2 2)
 LINESTRING(2 2,3 3)
 LINESTRING(3 3,4 4)
 LINESTRING(4 4,5 5)
 LINESTRING(5 5,6 6)
 LINESTRING(6 6,7 7)
 LINESTRING(7 7,8 8)
 LINESTRING(8 8,9 9)
 LINESTRING(9 9,10 10)
(9 rows)
```

This method taken from [PostGIS in Action, 2nd Edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1617291390) by Regina O. Obe and Leo S. Hsu.

Answer (score 3):

Here we dump the line as points using [`ST_DumpPoints`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DumpPoints.html) and then use a [window function to compute the line segments using `lead()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html). This method tended to be [slower than this method here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/227513/6052)

```
WITH t AS (
  SELECT ST_MakeLine(ST_MakePoint(x,x)) AS l
  FROM generate_series(1,10) AS x
)
SELECT linesegment
FROM (
  SELECT ST_AsText(ST_MakeLine(geom, lead(geom) OVER ())) AS linesegment
  FROM t
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL ST_DumpPoints(t.l)
    WITH ORDINALITY
  ORDER BY ordinality
) AS g
WHERE linesegment IS NOT NULL;

      linesegment      
-----------------------
 LINESTRING(1 1,2 2)
 LINESTRING(2 2,3 3)
 LINESTRING(3 3,4 4)
 LINESTRING(4 4,5 5)
 LINESTRING(5 5,6 6)
 LINESTRING(6 6,7 7)
 LINESTRING(7 7,8 8)
 LINESTRING(8 8,9 9)
 LINESTRING(9 9,10 10)
(9 rows)
```

Comment: I hate you... 20 minutes ago I was thinking I know SQL quite good... This 20 minutes took me just to understand what is happening in this query...

Comment: @Jendrusk what did you find hard to understand with this? I'll be happy to explain?

Comment: Thanx Evan - It's OK now. I had to read alittle about LATERAL and WITH ORDINALITY, also window functions deployment broke my vision of what you can and can't do in SQL, so I know they exists but can't learn to use them when they could be usefull... First resolution I had in mind was based on some FOR ... LOOP, function or anonymous block - this query is at least few levels better

Answer (score 1):

I suggest this form of the query (short syntax):

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_MakeLine(geom, next_geom)) AS linesegment
FROM  (
   SELECT ST_MakeLine(ST_MakePoint(x,x)) AS l
   FROM   generate_series(1,10) x
   ) t
JOIN   LATERAL (
   SELECT geom, lead(geom) OVER () AS next_geom
   FROM   ST_DumpPoints(l)
   ) p ON next_geom IS NOT NULL;
```

Also demonstrating a window function in a `LATERAL` subquery.
(Compare [Evan's comment on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#comment71378144_28557803)).

Or, more verbosely, to not depend on implementation details like order of rows or default column names:

```
SELECT path, ST_AsText(ST_MakeLine(geom, next_geom)) AS linesegment
FROM  (
   SELECT ST_MakeLine(ST_MakePoint(x,x)) AS l
   FROM   generate_series(1,10) x
   ) t
JOIN   LATERAL (
   SELECT path, geom, lead(geom) OVER (ORDER BY path) AS next_geom
   FROM   ST_DumpPoints(t.l) dp(path, geom)
   ) p ON next_geom IS NOT NULL
ORDER  BY path;
```

Since [`ST_DumpPoints()`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DumpPoints.html) returns a `path` column anyway, we don't need to add `WITH ORDINALITY`.