# Measure length of each segment for a polygon in Postgis

Tags: postgis, postgresql, polygon, linestring, length

I have a polygon table in PostGIS and need to calculate the length of each line segment.

[image]

How can I achieve this? I have done it in QGIS but would prefer to do it in the database. I have found a [solution in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/165574/qgis-how-to-label-individual-sides-of-polygon) to do this.

Answer (score 4):

You need to first get the boundary linestring of the polygon. You can do this with [`ST_Boundary`](http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_Boundary.html)

```
SELECT ST_AsText(x)
FROM ST_Boundary(
  ST_GeomFromText(
    $$POLYGON((0 0, 1 0, 1 1, 0 1, 0 0))$$
  )
)
  AS t(x);
            st_astext            
---------------------------------
 LINESTRING(0 0,1 0,1 1,0 1,0 0)  <- NOTE: LINESTRING() not POLYGON()
(1 row)
```

Now you need to solve problem of getting the individual line strings with only two points. For this we turn to [PostGIS in Action, 2nd Edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1617291390) by Regina O. Obe and Leo S. Hsu, Chapter 11. A book every GIS developer worth their salt should have already read.  [See this question for more details.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/227502/6052)

They use a method of `CROSS JOIN LATERAL` with `generate_series` and `ST_MakeLine`. As far as I know, there is no better method.

```
SELECT ST_AsText(t.geom), gs.*, ST_AsText(line.geom) AS line
FROM ST_Boundary(
  ST_GeomFromText(
    $$POLYGON((0 0, 1 0, 1 1, 0 1, 0 0))$$
  )
)
  AS t(geom)
CROSS JOIN LATERAL generate_series(1, ST_NPoints(geom) - 1)
  AS gs(x)
CROSS JOIN LATERAL ST_MakeLine(
  ST_PointN(geom, x),
  ST_PointN(geom, x+1)
) AS line(geom);
            st_astext            | x |        line         
---------------------------------+---+---------------------
 LINESTRING(0 0,1 0,1 1,0 1,0 0) | 1 | LINESTRING(0 0,1 0)
 LINESTRING(0 0,1 0,1 1,0 1,0 0) | 2 | LINESTRING(1 0,1 1)
 LINESTRING(0 0,1 0,1 1,0 1,0 0) | 3 | LINESTRING(1 1,0 1)
 LINESTRING(0 0,1 0,1 1,0 1,0 0) | 4 | LINESTRING(0 1,0 0)
(4 rows)
```

From this it's easy. Displaying the length is only adding `ST_Length(line.geom)` to the `SELECT` list however that's not too interesting since all of our lines have a length of 1. The perfect square I've chosen isn't the most interesting example; next time you can dump simplified data and your desired output with `ST_AsText()`.