# Iterating over LineString and applying filter in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, line, filter, linestring, iteration

I want to iterate over a LineString and apply a filter so that I create a new LineString with those points that succeed in the test. How do I do that?

My goal is to find some outliers that are too far from the rest of the points in the path and remove them from the result. So I would like to measure the distance between each point in the LineString to make sure that they are not too far from each other.

Comment: You could use [`ST_DumpPoints`](http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_DumpPoints.html)

Comment: You can get some inspiration [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/227502/how-to-break-apart-a-complex-line-segment-into-simple-line-segments-between-all) to extract each segment from the line, then you can compute their length and filter them and at last reconstruct the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `St_dump` your points from the LineString

order them by `St_linelocatePoint` and use a where condition to not use the points you don't want

and remake the LineString with `St_makeline` groupind by `"id"` of the line.

so something like this ... I guess

```
With points as (
select (St_dump(t.geom)).geom as geom, lt.id as lt_id
from linestring_table as lt)
select St_makeline(p.geom) from points as p,
from linestring_table as lt
where 'condition to keep point'
group by p.lt_id
order by St_linelocatePoint(lt.geom,p.geom)
```